# Return single json object from json array that matches minimum value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like this

```
     var data = [
      { i: 0, j: 0, day: 5 },
      { i: 1, j: 0, day: 3 },
      { i: 1, j: 1, day: 5 },
      { i: 1, j: 2, day: 10 },
      { i: 2, j: 0, day: 5 },
      { i: 3, j: 0, day: 5 },
      { i: 4, j: 0, day: 6 },
      { i: 4, j: 1, day: 10 }
    ]
```

I want to return a single row from JSON with minimum `day` value

For eg in the above array minimum `day` is `3` and i want to get

```
{ i: 1, j: 0, day: 3 }
```

as output

I have tried this method

`Math.min.apply(Math,data.map(function(item){return item.day}))` but it returns only the minimum `day`

One solution i found is using `indexOf` method but i don't think its a good practice. Is there any shorthand method ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return the element with the smaller `day` property.

For empty arrays, you need a check in advance, because

> Calling reduce on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

```js
var data = [{ i: 0, j: 0, day: 5 }, { i: 1, j: 0, day: 3 }, { i: 1, j: 1, day: 5 }, { i: 1, j: 2, day: 10 }, { i: 2, j: 0, day: 5 }, { i: 3, j: 0, day: 5 }, { i: 4, j: 0, day: 6 }, { i: 4, j: 1, day: 10 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.day < b.day ? a : b;
    });
    
console.log(result);
```